# Почему Masonry сетка иногда слипается?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, masonry

Есть элементы prntscr.com/i2hiuo , но иногда они прогружаются вот так prntscr.com/i2hj7z , при обновлении страниц без сброса кэша (обычным f5) всё становится как надо, но почему изначально не работает ? При ресайзе, так же сетка становится нормальной.

```js
var $MasGrid = $('.snb-mas-grid'); 
$MasGrid.masonry({ //
  itemSelector: '.snb-mas-item',
  columnWidth: '.snb-mas-item',
  horizontalOrder: true,
  percentPosition: true 
});
```

```html
<div class="snb-mas-grid row">
    
  <div class="snb-mas-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <div class="snb-item">

      <div class="snb-img">
        <img src="img/ri-1.jpg" alt="img">
      </div>

      <div class="snb-descr-block">

        <div class="snb-d-top-cont">
          <span class="snb-b-date-1">18</span>
          <span class="snb-b-date-2">Ноября</span>
          <a href="#" class="gray-btn"><span class="no-tran">Гаджеты</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="snb-d-main-cont">
          <a href="#" class="snb-dmc-a">Новый эксклюзивный образ: 
          Хекстек-Ког'Мао</a>
          <p class="snb-dmc-p">Хекстек-Ког'Мао принесет в ваш дом радость 
          и огневую мощь. Образ уже доступен за 
          10 самоцветов.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="snb-mas-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <div class="snb-item">

      <div class="snb-img">
        <img src="img/ri-2.jpg" alt="img">
      </div>

      <div class="snb-descr-block">

        <div class="snb-d-top-cont">
          <span class="snb-b-date-1">18</span>
          <span class="snb-b-date-2">Ноября</span>
          <a href="#" class="gray-btn"><span class="no-tran">Гаджеты</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="snb-d-main-cont">
          <a href="#" class="snb-dmc-a">Олимпийский комитет против игр <br>
          с насилием, взрывами <br>
          и убийствами</a>
          <p class="snb-dmc-p">Новый комментарий по этому вопросу 
          от президента олимпийского комитета
          Томаса Баха.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="snb-mas-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

    <div class="snb-item">

      <div class="snb-img">
        <img src="img/ri-3.jpg" alt="img">
      </div>

      <div class="snb-descr-block">

        <div class="snb-d-top-cont">
          <span class="snb-b-date-1">18</span>
          <span class="snb-b-date-2">Ноября</span>
          <a href="#" class="gray-btn"><span class="no-tran">Гаджеты</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="snb-d-main-cont">
          <a href="#" class="snb-dmc-a">Карточная Dota может выйти 
          и в физическом виде</a>
          <p class="snb-dmc-p">Valve оформила марку для физической 
          карточной игры/набора игральных карт
          Dota 2.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил загрузку картинок до построения сетки - результат тот же.

Но если дописать обновлении сетки через setTimeout(function() {$MasGrid.masonry();}, 50) то есть спустя 0.05 секунды после загрузки картинок, то она встает как надо, не знаю хорошее это решение или нет :)

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/229329)

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, ну, вообще решение в ответе есть - обновлять сетку с задержкой.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вопрос звучал как "Почему слипается?", а не "Как сделать как надо?", по-этому я решил, что это не исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, ну, ответ может не быть идеальным и даже правильным, но при этом решать проблему автора вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте обертку `$(window).bind('load', function() {...});`